# Why is the statement "println ['a']" wrong?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Programming language: groovy

I tried to print an array `["a", "b", "c"]` via `println ["a", "b", "c"]`, but I got a prompt: Could not get unknown property 'println' for project ':test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Why `println 3` and `["a", "b", "c"].size()` is ok, but `println ["a", "b", "c"].size()` is wrong?

I tried passing an array as a parameter to a method (by removing the parentheses), but couldn't get it to work. unless parentheses

Comment: Rather you should try println (["a", "b", "c"].size())

Comment: Yes, but I want to know why the parentheses are definitely required when printing an array but not when printing a string

Comment: The operator () has higher precedence than operator [ ]. Hence whenever you are making a method call, the method is expecting a parenthesis of type () followed by logic inside it. If you give [ ] , that's not how Groovy compiler is designed to work. Otherwise you'll encounter MissingPropertyException.

Comment: I See, but I still have doubts: why the brackets in the statement println "message" can be omitted, but the brackets in println(["a", "b", "c"]) cannot be omitted?

Comment: `a [b]` corresponds to `a.getAt(b)`. So, `a` should be a property for this call.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, the use of println [...] will be considered by the compiler to read a certain value of the instance of println, and will not be considered a method call.

Comment: What do you mean by "Instance of println" ?

Comment: @stardep if you write smth like `println[ 'a' ]`, the compiler treats it as a subscript operator (getAt() method) on `println` object